# Google bigquery selects NULL values when using NOT IN

Tags: google-bigquery

The following, somewhat artificial, query selects entries which have a `NULL` value, which I would not have expected.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN some_column NOT IN (
            'value_which_does_not_exist1', 'value_which_does_not_exist2'
        ) THEN true
        ELSE false
        END match,
        COUNT(some_column) n_events
FROM 'some_table'
GROUP BY match
```

The number of match which are false is exactly equal to the number of rows with `NULL` in `some_colum`. This is a problem for real queries where I have to use `NOT IN`.
Why is `NOT IN` behaving like that?
And is there a 'better' way to handle this case than just adding a `WHERE some_column IS NOT NULL` after `FROM 'some_table'`?
Better in the sense that one does not needs to remember to account for `NULL` values every time one uses `NOT IN`, e.g., stop using `NOT IN` and replace it with use some other technique.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried ````SELECT CASE WHEN SOME_COL IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END````

Comment: Because of adding some_column IS NOT NULL is too long, usually I use COALESCE(some_column, '') to handle NULL filter, and include that empty_string('') to the filter (in or out) based on your needs. **sometimes using other than empty_string is necessary if there are empty_string value inside the column. So I use COALESCE(some_column, 'null_value'), then using 'null_value' included in the filter.

Comment: It would be great to have sample data and a desired output in order to help you.